# How to make an existing project folder, an SVN repository and push it to a remote repo

Tags: git, svn, version-control, repository, push

I am currently working on an angular application. I was given the URL of an SVN repo where i am expected to push my code. I have worked with git previously but am completely new to SVN. I am on Ubuntu and have installed subversion.

Some online solutions i've found stated that i should create a new SVN repo and import my code into it but I would like to initiate svn in my already existing project folder (like git init). I have tried multiple commands like svn checkout, svn import etc.. as per online sources but I am not sure i am doing it right.

Is there a straight forward way of making an existing project a svn repo (working copy?) and then pushing the code into a remote repo from command line on Ubuntu. TIA

Comment: `I was given the URL of an SVN repo where i am expected to push my code`, at this URL, does the code you're working on already exist or are you making an entirely new project in this repository? Without giving away any proprietary information, is the URL you were giving something like `http://example.com/repo/trunk/MyAngular/Application` or did it stop at trunk?

Comment: You can use the command `svnadmin create reponame` to create a local svn repo.

Comment: The url is in the '../trunk/AppName' format

Comment: The repo at the url is empty as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a project folder in the remote repo, either:

- Checkout out a working copy of the parent folder, then commit the new subdirectory (you do not need to keep this working copy)
- Or, use `svn mkdir` to create the subdirectory directly within the remote repo in the appropriate parent folder.

Then you can checkout that new project folder on top of your existing project folder. Use `svn status` to see all of your uncontrolled files, which can then be added and committed to the remote repo.